# Tortoise puts question marks on all my root folders

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using the SVN tool Tortoise for some java projects.

It has decided to put question marks on all my folders under the C:\ directory. This is not what I was expecting as I cannot see any **.svn** folders at the C:\ level. All my project work is under the **hwoffice** folder.

Anyone?

[image]

Comment: You need to add this files into repository and commit it (If you want to store this in repository).

Answer (score 3):

The Folder/ Path where these files resides has SVN reference but the folders/files with blue question mark are not yet committed to the SVN repository.

If you are using WIndows OS, You can just right click and choose SVN-Commit to add these to file repository.

By the way You should create separate specific folders and add them SVN, checking entire drive is not an intelligent idea.

If you have already checked in the entire drive, just search for .svn (that is default extension for svn files, or see in settings of svn) and delete all .svn files.

[image]

You can also choose export option from SVN to get the files without SVN reference, but in this case your c: drive remains mapped, so search and delete .svn shall get you desired results.

Comment: but the problem is i cant find any SVN reference (there is no .SVN folder... i can also see hiden files)

Comment: i know its a very stupid idea... it was an accident, now i cant undo it

Comment: there is only one .SVN folder and thats under the hwoffice directory :(

Comment: IF all .svn files are deleted, just refresh the view or parse the files by opening that folder and coming back to root folder, windows usually keeps folder images cached by this it shall be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me.

1) In Windows Explorer, Tools -> Folder Options -> View tab -> Show hidden files, folders and drives.

2) Navigate into the root folder which has question marks in files/folders. Delete the .svn hidden folder there (which appears in the same directory as that of the question marked ones).